# Dot Net Core, Cryptography, I am getting different encrypted value for same string each time

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core, cryptography

I am trying to store and retrieve userid/password for database login from Asp.Net core application. since this is sensitive information, I have attempted encryption/decryption.

Here is my encryption/decryption class.

```
 public class EncryptorDecryptor
{

    public static string Encrypt(string text, string key)
    {
        var _key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(_key, aes.IV))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                        {
                            sw.Write(text);
                        }
                    }

                    var iv = aes.IV;

                    var encrypted = ms.ToArray();

                    var result = new byte[iv.Length + encrypted.Length];

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypted, 0, result, iv.Length, encrypted.Length);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string encrypted, string key)
    {
        var b = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);

        var iv = new byte[16];
        var cipher = new byte[16];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(b, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);

        var _key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(_key, iv))
            {
                var result = string.Empty;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(cipher))
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                        {
                            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for consuming the encryption/decryption class

```
 var name = "santu_ghosh";
            var pword = "p@ssword";
             string key = "E546C8DF278CD5931069B522E695D4F2";
            var encnm = EncryptorDecryptor.Encrypt(name, key);
            var encpwd = EncryptorDecryptor.Encrypt(pword,key);
```

My problem is that I am getting a different value for encnm (encrypted name) and encpwd (encrypted password). As such this algorithm is unusable for my purpose.

My requirement is simple. I want an encryption algorithm (not necessarily AES or triple DES), that gives the same output each time in Dot net core. So I will be able to save this in appsettings.json and retrieve and decrypt, and each time the application runs, I should get the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay so when you call Encrypt with name + key and then Decrypt with encrypted value + key you get something different back?

Comment: That's because IV gets randomized when you don't explicitly set it.

Comment: Thank you 500, I will try to set it and see the outcome.

Comment: may I ask what problem comes with having different ciphertexts each time? I've seen numerous cases where people stumbled over this and hardcoded an IV and thus weakened their security...

Comment: Hi DarkSquirrel42, try getting encrypted value from any string (assume it is the database password), then store it in appsettings.json file. when the appilcation runs the next time, try to decrypt it with the same algorithm as listed above. then try to login to the database (thru application)  with this decrypted password. You will know what problem i faced.